# Anyone tried using IgniteRDD/IgniteSQL of accessing Spark datasets using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

We have a need to share the RDDs across multiple sessions. I see option of using Java to access Ignite RDD/Ignite SQL of accessing Spark datasets. Anyone tried using IgniteRDD/IgniteSQL of accessing Spark datasets using Scala.

Answer (score 1):

`IgniteRDD` is a Scala class and Scala is fully supported by Ignite.

Comment: How do I convert a igniteRDD to a dataframe or a data set?